# two way data binding between ng-model and directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Case :**

I am trying to watch the change of a select list through a directive then add html based on the selected value but for some reason I am unable to watch the change in the link function . any idea ? thanks

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item as item.type for item in itemsList"></select>

<d-input type="selected.type"></d-input>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('dInput', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            type : '=',
        } ,
        template : '<div></div>',
         link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(scope.type, function() {
            var tmplt = '' ;
            if (scope.type == 'input')
                tmplt = '<input type ="text" name="inputname" value="0">';
            if (scope.type== 'select')
                tmplt = '<select ><option> option1</option><option>option2</option></select>';
            if (scope.type == 'radio')
                tmplt = '<input type ="radio" name="inputname" value="0">';

           element.html(tmplt);
           $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            });                                   
        },  
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the first parameter of the `$watch` function:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    return scope.type;
}, function() {

    ....
});
```

Comment: @RawanNj Take a look at the `$watch` section and the example: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: alright :) another question please , what about the '=' in the scope object , at first i thought this works for binding and i dont need watch to monitor changes, so whenever the value of ng-model is changed it will change .. is it only to pass the parameter and be able to change it from scope but can not monitor the change ?

Comment: @RawanNj `=` means two way binding. You can change the value from the directive/controller/view and the change will reflect on the other end.

Comment: @OmariAhron exactly so when it's changed from the view it should reflect in the directive ! so why do I need the watch

Comment: @RawanNj Ah sorry, just now got what you mean. It should work, if it doesn't you can try to watch the `selected` instead of `selected.type`. If that still doesn't work try to create a fiddle and a new question :)